# Since we have operator<=> in C++20, is operator== still needed?

Tags: c++, c++20, equality

I'm in the process of learning how comparisons work in C++20 and I'm struggling to understand one thing: since `operator<=>` has to check for equality do we really need a separate `operator==`? For example, the following check:

```
a == b
```

could be rewritten (by the compiler) as:

```
a.operator<=>(b) == 0
```

but instead, it will still try to call `operator==`. Wouldn't it make more sense to deprecate `operator==` and just use `operator<=>` for both ordering and equality? In a case a class needs some custom ordering one has to implement both `operator<=>` and `operator==` which creates an additional room for error. Is there a reason there are now two ways to check for equality?

Comment: `<=>` synthesizes `<` and `>` and `<=` and `>=`.  `==` synthesizes `!=`.  The reason being that `<=>` cannot generate an efficient `==`.

Comment: The compiler can't know using a custom `<=>` is more or less efficient than a custom `==`. It assumes it isn't. You can still tell it to do so by defining `operator` as `= default;` explicitly.